# Loading data from Angular AJAX-call into D3-graph

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, d3.js

I'm having some trouble loading JSON-data from an external API into a D3-graph. I'm using Quandl's API to load brent oil price-rates over a period of time, which is the data I'm trying to graph. I'm making use of Angular in my project, so I have a service set up to make the AJAX-call and then provide it to the scope. This I can do successfully as long as I don't try to involve my D3-code.

When I do, I get several errors:

> GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

and this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

which is tied to some error in my d3-code I cannot well understand.

Here is the full code producing the errors:

```
app.service('oilService', function($http) {
  delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  this.getData = function() {
  var URL = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/CHRIS/ICE_B1.json";
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: URL
  })
}})

.directive('oilGraph', function() {
  return {
   scope: {},
   controller: function(oilService) {
    var width = 200;
  var height = 100;

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%y-%m-%d");

  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  var valueline = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.settle); });
  var svg = d3.select("#oilgraph").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

  oilService.getData()
  .then(function(data) {
    d3.json(data, function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseTime(d[0]);
        d.settle = d[4];
      })

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.settle; })]);

      svg.append("path")
          .data([data])
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", valueline);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      svg.append("g")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    })
   })
  }
 }
})
```

(nevermind the curly brackets-mess)

Comment: The second error is because `data` in  `data.forEach(function(d) {...` is undefined - due to the first error. Could you log the result of `oilService.getData()` by putting a console.log here: `.then(function(data) { console.log("data:", data)`? Could you also post what the result of `console.log(error);` is? (I am guessing it is the first error but just in case)

Comment: $http most probably [deserializes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations) the JSON data (that would be the default), so d3.json already gets an object, not a string

Comment: @ccprog that's definitely one of the issues, but what I cannot understand at this point is why the localhost part in the first error:
 `http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] ` . I mean this is not constructed anywhere in the code and `d3.json` takes as input the `data` from `oilService.getData()` so something there must be fishy..

Comment: @mkaran The first console.log("data:", data) returns an object.

Comment: cf. the [signature](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json): `d3.json(url[, callback])`. Your data object is interpreted as a file system uri.

Comment: @ccprog indeed! So just remove the `d3.json` and load directly the data

Comment: @ccprog Makes sense, although I don't need the JSON-call in this case? The error disappeared once I removed the JSON-parsing call. I now only have the second error.

Comment: @SudokuNinja is it the same error after you removed the d3.json ? Btw for `forEach` to work, the data need to be a list.

Comment: @mkaran Yep, the uncaught type-error is still there.

Comment: @mkaran Well, it says `TypeError: data.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @SudokuNinja it is as ccprog answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular $http allready deserializes the data. Either do not call d3.json, or let it handle the request and do not call $http.

The data received from https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/CHRIS/ICE_B1.json follow another format than you are expecting. They look like this:

```
{
  //...
  "column_names": [ "Date","Open","High","Low","Settle","Change","Wave","Volume","Prev. Day Open Interest","EFP Volume","EFS Volume","Block Volume" ],
  "data": [
     ["2017-06-28",46.25,47.47,46.25,47.31,0.66,46.85,158984.0,149270.0,2218.0,null,1379.0],
     //...
}
```

To get at what you want you need to reference

```
oilService.getData()
  .then(function(response) {
    var mapped_data = response.data.data.map(function(d) {
        return {
           date: parseTime(d[0]),
           settle: d[4]
        };
     })

    //...

    svg.append("path")
       .data([mapped_data])
       //etc.
  })
```

Comment: `data.data.map is not a function`

Comment: I could reference the data just fine if I write it like this `data.data.data.forEach(function(d) { .... })`
This also works for: `data.data.data.map`
My only problem now is the graph is not showing anything except a vertical y-axis line.

Comment: ah - Angular $http also wraps the JSON object in a `.data` property. To avoid naming that is too silly, maybe the callback parameter should be called `response`, as the Angular doc does.